# Howt to convert utf-8 byte offsets to utf-8 character offsets

Tags: python, utf-8, character, byte, offset

I need to post-process the output of a legacy tool that reports utf-8 byte offsets instead of utf-8 character offsets.
For example, it'll report `[0, 1, 3, 4, 6]` instead of `[0, 1, 2, 3, 4]` for the 5 characters in the seven-byte utf-8 string `'aβgδe'`, because the Greek letters 'β' and 'δ' are encoded as two-byte-sequences. (The actual text may also contain 3-byte and 4-byte utf-8 sequences.)

Are there any built-in Python functions that I could use to convert utf-8 byte offsets to utf-8 character offsets?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand correctly. Why not to use b-strings. So you have the byte-offset. Then for python you just use a string (so you have the "character offset, but a string is not UTF-8). Eventually you decode/encode at need (to have correct indices [if extra CPU is not a problem]). Else you can build a offset table, but just encoding one character at a time (and checking the len): a simple list compression. (good if the string is not huge [as a book/large file])

Comment: When I had a similar problem, I didn't find a way short of encoding the string to UTF-8 and then creating a byte-to-charater-offset table; implemented [here](https://github.com/lfurrer/bconv/blob/f7418a8fdb772ca1b086c52e6db57a2758b82c44/bconv/fmt/bioc.py#L581-L586).

Comment: @lenz apparently, there's no way around creating a byte-to-character-offset table. 
Can you please add your code as an answer so that I can upvote it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think there is a built-in or std-lib utility for this, but you can write your own small function to create a byte-offset-to-codepoint-offset mapping.

#### Naive approach

```
import typing as t

def map_byte_to_codepoint_offset(text: str) -> t.Dict[int, int]:
    mapping = {}
    byte_offset = 0
    for codepoint_offset, character in enumerate(text):
        mapping[byte_offset] = codepoint_offset
        byte_offset += len(character.encode('utf8'))
    return mapping
```

Let's test this with your example:

```
>>> text = 'aβgδe'
>>> byte_offsets = [0, 1, 3, 4, 6]
>>> mapping = map_byte_to_codepoint_offset(text)
>>> mapping
{0: 0, 1: 1, 3: 2, 4: 3, 6: 4}
>>> [mapping[o] for o in byte_offsets]
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4]
```

#### Optimisation

I haven't benchmarked this, but it's probably not very efficient to call `.encode()` on every character separately. Furthermore, we're only interested in the byte length of the encoded character, which can only take one of four values corresponding to a contiguous range of codepoints each.
To get these ranges, one can study the UTF-8 encoding specs, look them up on the internet, or run a quick calculation in the Python REPL:

```
>>> import sys
>>> bins = {i: [] for i in (1, 2, 3, 4)}
>>> for codepoint in range(sys.maxunicode+1):
...     # 'surrogatepass' required to allow encoding surrogates in UTF-8
...     length = len(chr(codepoint).encode('utf8', errors='surrogatepass'))
...     bins[length].append(codepoint)
...
>>> for l, cps in bins.items():
...     print(f'{l}: {hex(min(cps))}..{hex(max(cps))}')
...
1: 0x0..0x7f
2: 0x80..0x7ff
3: 0x800..0xffff
4: 0x10000..0x10ffff
```

Furthermore, the mapping returned in the naive approach contains gaps: if we look up an offset that is in the middle of a multi-byte character, we will get a KeyError (eg. there's no key `2` in the above example). To avoid this, we can fill the gaps by repeating the codepoint offsets. Since the resulting indices will be successive integers starting from 0, we can use a list instead of a dict for the mapping.

```
TWOBYTES = 0x80
THREEBYTES = 0x800
FOURBYTES = 0x10000

def map_byte_to_codepoint_offset(text: str) -> t.List[int]:
    mapping = []
    for codepoint_offset, character in enumerate(text):
        mapping.append(codepoint_offset)
        codepoint = ord(character)
        for cue in (TWOBYTES, THREEBYTES, FOURBYTES):
            if codepoint >= cue:
                mapping.append(codepoint_offset)
            else:
                break
    return mapping
```

With the example from above:

```
>>> mapping = map_byte_to_codepoint_offset(text)
>>> mapping
[0, 1, 1, 2, 3, 3, 4]
>>> [mapping[o] for o in byte_offsets]
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4]
```